# Disable animations in BlueprintJS?

Tags: blueprintjs

Is there a way to disable animations completely for a component? Our use case is we want to use Popover, but we don't want the extra time baked in for animations to take place. We want the show/hide to be instant.

Should I override the CSS here, or is there a better hook to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adjust the opening/closing delay for the popover by setting the props `hoverOpenDelay` and `hoverCloseDelay` to `0`.